# Ooozie simple authentication configuration

Tags: authentication, hadoop, oozie

Oozie beginner here. I wish to run a program with `simple` authentication. However, when trying to execute a client program I get the following error.

```
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA002: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:462)
at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:436)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1132)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1286)
at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getDelegationToken(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:313)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getRMDelegationToken(YarnClientImpl.java:517)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.getDelegationToken(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getDelegationToken(YARNRunner.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getDelegationToken(Cluster.java:401)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$16.run(JobClient.java:1232)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$16.run(JobClient.java:1229)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getDelegationToken(JobClient.java:1228)
at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createJobClient(HadoopAccessorService.java:440)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createJobClient(JavaActionExecutor.java:1329)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1080)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getDelegationToken(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:310)
... 30 more
```

My oozie-site.xml configuration file is

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>oozie.service.AuthorizationService.security.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value> 
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.type</name>
    <value>simple</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.kerberos.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<!-- Proxyuser Configuration -->
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.ubuntu.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.ubuntu.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property> 
<property>
   <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.hadoop.configurations</name>
   <value>*=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
   <value>/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Any help appreciated.